# Easiest way to change the URL for the banner logo on many subsites in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

A client has created a site collection with many (hundreds) of subsites. The logo in on each subsite takes them to the subsites welcome page but what the client wants is to link to the very top site welcome page in the site collection. How is this done in the easiest way (instead of having to change manually on each site)? Powershell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the link in the masterpage to accomplish this.
Open the masterpage in e.g. SharePoint Designer in Split mode. Select the logo and adjust the control SPLinkButton. The NavigateUrl value is default "~site". Change this to "~sitecollection". Save, check in and approve the masterpage.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this would be that the file you need to edit is called v4.master under the master pages.

Comment: How is it possible programmatically?